# Understanding sequential solution for the TAOCP 3 Million Men problem

Tags: algorithms, sorting

The problem and solution of interest is described here: [What does > mean in this TAOCP solution?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/52428/what-does-mean-in-this-taocp-solution)

Can anyone explain following points in that solution:

1. How exactly we can build (x[i], x[i+2]) for 1 <= i <= N-2 ?
2. What exactly means "merge G with it"? Provide exact algorithm for merging these two files.
3. How steps 1-4 are executed? Is it:

   ```
   if (condition 1) {
       ....
   }
   if (condition 2) {
       ....
   }
   if (condition 3) {
       ....
   }
   if (condition 4) {
       ....
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   if (condition 1) {
       ....
   }
   else if (condition 2) {
       ....
   }
   else if (condition 3) {
       ....
   }
   else if (condition 4) {
       ....
   }
   ```

   ?

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. With a `for` loop that steps through the array and creates a new pair from the $i$th and $(i+2)$th elements, for each $i$.
2. The same as the merge step in merge sort.
3. There are no "otherwise"s in the statement in English, so there should be no `else` statements.

Comment: possible to explain with an example of sorting {(b,c),(a,b),(d,e),(c,d)}?